# How to redirecr a sub domain except a PHP file by .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I 'm going  to redirect all request to a subdoma into an IP using .htaccess file  except all request to splash.php file.

I used the following code in sub domain folder, but it redirect all requests (even splash.php).

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mydomian\.edu$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.mydomain\.edu$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/212\.99\.xx\.xx" [R=301,L]
```

please tell me what i should to add to this code to prevent redirection of my splash.php file.

I used apache and linux on my server.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.mydomian\.edu$ [NC]
RewriteRule !splash\.php http://212.99.xx.xx%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: it returns File not found!

Comment: +1, That rewrite packs a punch! Didn't know you could use `!` in the RewriteRule, and I always forget that there's no need for a `/` before the `%{REQUEST_URI}` :)